# Eclipse Plug-in, How to create BlockComment in JDT?

Tags: eclipse-jdt

We can create Javadoc like shown below:

```
Javadoc javadoc = ast.newJavadoc();
javadoc.tags().add(tagElement);
```

and the BlockComment ?

```
BlockComment blockComment = ast.newBlockComment();
blockComment.set ???(set what)???
```

Thank you.

Comment: Basically, you need identify the position you want to insert first, and then create a String Placeholder for insertion. [insert comment example](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/06/add-comments-by-using-eclipse-jdt-astrewrite/)

Answer (score 1):

**Straight from the JavaDocs :**

Note that this node type is a `comment placeholder`, and is only useful for recording the source range where a comment was found in a source string. It is `not useful for creating comments`.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the API doc. For a block comment, you can set either a bunch of comments or javadoc comments.